# What could cause my browser to load a nonexistant webpage other than a browser's cached files?

Tags: wordpress, apache, caching

I am working in AMPPS on a wordpress theme (on a Mac OS). While working on the pages.php file, I made some changes and saw no effect. As a test, I temporarily deleted all code in the file and saved it. For some reason, the link ISN'T broken...it loads the page as if the code was all there. So I tried to trash the file, and now a nonexistent page is loading. It loads page.php even though the file isn't even in the theme's folder. I've tried clearing my cache, restarting the browser, even using a different browser. Nothing works...the page keeps loading as if frozen with some very specific exact code. It's acting like it's a cached file, but I've even disabled cache under developer tools (in Chrome). That wouldn't explain why it's loading in Firefox anyway.

What could be causing this and how do I fix it? It seems I'm not seeing ANY changes that are made to that page.php file... no changes in HTML and no changes even if the file is trashed or all the code is deleted. Is this an apache cache? (I never set one up).

This has got to be a cache somewhere...right? Not sure how to fix it?

Comment: don't think there are some issues. you're just trying to modify the file, which is not related to the page you're refreshing. if you'll be more specific( provide url example, which you're trying to modify, provide theme name, or theme templates hierarchy with all file names ),we will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your theme. Wordpress will default to index.php in the absence of a page.php file. If you disable all caching plugins I wouldn't think cache would be a factor. One thing that may help you figure this out is adding the following line of code to your page.php, index.php and any other page templates you have (single.php, archive.php, etc).

```
<?php echo __FILE__; ?>
```

Comment: I am custom designing a theme along with a tutorial book.

I added the code to the index page and it showed up fine. I added the code to the page.php page and it didn't show up. I tried adding just plain text to the page.php page and it didn't how up either. No changes that I make to the page.php file go into effect.

Comment: Can you post your page.php file or theme structure?

Comment: What do you mean by theme structure? Do you mean the directory structure? Not sure how to post that. But in the wordpress themes folder I have the simple folder (theme). In that I have blog1.jpg, footer.php, functions.php, header.php, index.php, page.php, screenshot.png, single.php, and style.php

Comment: Ohhhh thank you! It turns out, wordpress was building the post page off of single.php instead of pages.php. When I removed the single.php file, wordpress started pulling it from the pages.php file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Apparently Wordpress was taking the information from single.php and using that. Any changes I made to single.php would go into affect. Once I removed single.php, then Wordpress started pulling the code from pages.php